# appreciate feedback on CDC approaches in SQL

Tags: sql, cdc

https://github.com/surbhi-nijhara/techtumblr/blob/master/ms-sql-guide/doc_source/ms-sql-cdc-approaches.md

Disclaimer: This is a review ask. I believe the SQL approaches would be a good start for the similar business problem.

Comment: I guess https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be the appropriate place for code reviews.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as **Needs more focus**. If you post on CR please read the help center pages - especially [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @VN'sCorner If there was code, perhaps. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Commercial applications like IBM Data Replication are commonly employed to feed events (insert, update, deletes to in-scope tables) to external systems like Kafka or other databases.

While custom coding introduced in the application prior to updating the database, database triggers, and the database change capture audit capability are all options, they require more maintenance, monitoring and work to ensure all edge conditions are met.